# How to detect groups of circles with openCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, object-recognition

I have a picture like that below.
I would like to find groups of circles (their positions) in the image. 
In the following example there should be three groups. The background is white or will be whitish color.

(In the source image there will not be such rectangulars. I have just painted to show how groups should be like)

Is it possible to find it?

[image: Circles do detect]

What about such picture:
  [image: Example 2]

Circles without rectangulars:
[image: Example 3]

[image: Example 4]

Comment: can you add image without those rectangles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Simply invert the image,

2 - then dilate the image so that all circles are joined together,

3 - Find the contours,

4 - find bounding box.

eg :

[image]

Comment: Will dilating the image link the circles if there would be for instance: CCC  CC       C (C - Circle), long spaces between them?

Comment: It depends on the number of iterations,kernel used etc.

Comment: For eg, in your case, for 2 iterations, there was a split in grouping, while 5 gave correct answer.

Comment: Oh no. you won't get that much.

Comment: What about the last picture I have inserted?

Comment: You wont be able to group those wide gap circles with my method. otherwise it is ok as i have shown in my answer.

Comment: what does "dilating" mean? Blurring?

Comment: No. it takes a small window and replaces center element by the maximum value in that window. Here, we have binary image where i made circles white. So when window operates on all pixels, whenever a white comes inside the window, replaces central element by white. Thus it increases the area of white part, making circles to join each other. Its opposite is erosion. Check Docs.

Comment: Using dilatation is a very situational and not a robust solution. HoughCircles is way more correct.

Comment: @Moia. Totally agree.

Answer (score 2):

You have to identify the circles using `HoughCircles` and then use [clusterisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) ([K-Means algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_algorithm)). OpenCV has K-Means implementation: see [example1](http://www.aishack.in/2010/08/k-means-clustering-in-opencv/), [example2](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/kmeans.cpp?rev=4227) and [docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/clustering_and_search_in_multi-dimensional_spaces.html).

Answer (score 1):

HoughCircles has as one of its parameters the distance between possible circles before they are considered separate circles.  Simply keep tweaking this parameter.  As long as your groups of circles are farther apart than the actual circles in each group, HoughCircles will count each circle as part of the same 'circle'.

If your groups of circles overlap, though, then this won't work.  You'd have to separate each group somehow.  Maybe if all the circles in a group are in a line (like in your pictures) then the basic Hough line detection would give you the lines - then you could check for parallel lines that are close together, and those would indicate each group?